# how to learn Drools or another rule engine fast

Tags: java, drools, business-rules

We're embarking on a module which will generate some recommendations based on some criteria. The criteria will be in the form of set of Business Rules and hence I was considering using a Business Rule Engine like Drools(open source and java :-) )

we need to learn Drools fast (2-3 weeks) and be able to implement rules using JBoss Drools. Which articles, tutorials, books, best practices should we be following ?

Comment: it tool me a few days to get to grips with Drools.
I'm still not convinced by it, even if part of the UK tax office uses it.

Comment: You can find good JBoss Drools tutorial here along with source code and Videos-http://javainuse.com/drools

Comment: I have a step-by-step video course for beginners to learn Drools: https://www.udemy.com/course/master-drools/?referralCode=ED7C311E09498C940742

Answer (score 41):

What joekutner said + a recent [1hr Fosdem "introduction" video](http://video.fosdem.org/2010/devrooms/jboss/drools.ogg).  Despite the comments, it's actually really good, but what you *have* to have is [the slides](http://community.jboss.org/servlet/JiveServlet/download/10741-264-7610/fosdem2010markp.odp), so that you can follow through in a sane fashion.  [Here is a link to the Youtube-Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iAZY3dmih_k).

It is fast, you'll have to pause, but I found that I was learning stuff at the 25 minute mark after having done a few days playing and reading drools docs.

I can't emphasise how good this was helping me get the "feel" of drools, and just how to use the power.

Comment: Since I had a bit of trouble converting the video format (it's in .ogg), I figured I would save others the time by uploading it to youtube http://youtu.be/iAZY3dmih_k

Comment: Great advice! I've invested the time and it was a big help.

Answer (score 15):

The Drools Documentation is really good:

http://www.jboss.org/drools/documentation.html

There are two books from PackIt publishing that aren't bad:

https://www.packtpub.com/drools-jboss-rules-5-0-developers-guide/book

https://www.packtpub.com/jboss-drools-business-rules/book

Here's a good article that discusses rule-engines in general:

http://www.infoq.com/articles/Rule-Engines

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to just go through only one book

**Drools JBoss Rules 5.0 Developer's Guide, By James Taylor & Michal Bali**

It is very nice book check this out, and online lots of material is available.